# <expression> expected, got '=' for variable assignment in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I've created following Groovy class in IntelliJ IDEA

```
1. package org.seleniumrun
2. 
3. class Testing {
4.     static void getJsonAsString(String endPointUrl) {
5.        BufferedReader in = null;
6.     }
7.  .......
8. }
```

But it gives compilation error  `<expression> expected, got '='` at line number 6. I'm not getting how it is incorrect. Could you please help correct me if something is wrong here?

Comment: `in` is a keyword ([full list](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_keywords))

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realized this mistake as I'm new to Groovy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`in` is a reserved word used for loops. Rename it to something else (line 5) and its will work

Here is an example:

```
​class Testing {
    static void getJsonAsString(String endPointUrl) { 
         BufferedReader reader= null; 
         println"hello: $endPointUrl"
    } 
}

def t = new Testing()
t.getJsonAsString(​"http://google.com")​​​​​​​​​

// and this is how "in" can be used
for( i in [1,2,3,4]) {
   println i
}​
```

This is a working code that prints:

```
hello: http://google.com
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: Thanks! This is silly mistake I didn't realized as I'm new to Groovy.